ROS2 EffortController vs PositionController
I am trying to set up a joint group position controller for Ros2 for a robotic hexapod. The servos that I plan on using only have position feedback and I am wondering whether I should use a position controller or an effort controller.
Logically, it would make sense to use a position controller, but all resources that I have found online seem to use an effort controller.
controller_manager:
  ros__parameters:
    update_rate: 1000 # Hz
    use_sim_time: true

    # Define controllers and then give type.

[?]  joint_position_controller:
[?]    type: position_controllers/JointGroupPositionController

[?]  joint_effort_controller:
[?]    type: effort_controllers/JointGroupPositionController


Is there any difference functionally, that I should be aware of?
TIA, for the assistance.


all resources that I have found online seem to use an effort controller.

It will help with context if you link one or more of these resources in your post.
If your servos have only a position control interface, yes, you should use position_controllers/JointGroupPositionController
Some actuators have a torque or current interface and you could use an effort controller in principle... Like here for Dynamixel actuators:
https://github.com/Leung555/db_alpha_interface?tab=readme-ov-file#torque-control-torque-current-linear-relationship
However, note that the controller effort_controllers/JointGroupPositionController uses joint effort commands to achieve a joint position setpoint.
These were available in ROS 1:
https://github.com/ros-controls/ros_controllers/blob/c2348e85abf35cf33cf654a84d61db206abe9a73/effort_controllers/src/joint_group_position_controller.cpp#L61
There, the controlled variable and sensor feedback is joint position, but the controller computes torque or force commands to drive the actuator to the setpoint.
I don't believe this controller has been ported to ROS 2 yet, so even if you had a servo that supported torque or current commands, you'd have to implement the controller yourself anyway.

For position-controlled axis with effort command interface one could use the PID controller or joint_trajectory_controller

Ah, the generic PID controller makes sense and uncomplicates things.
